# The Avast antivirus causes an error when sending emails in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, email, smtp, antivirus

When Avast antivirus is disabled sending emails works properly. But when it is enabled sending the emails failed and I got the error below.
I found some answers about editing settings in Avast but if I am right that will resolve the error only on my computer but the error will stay for others?
That is not the solution I need. (https://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/187513-avast-blocking-your-email-heres-fix.html)

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
> failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad
> greeting from SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587, response: 421
> Cannot connect to SMTP server ::ffff:74.125.140.109
> (::ffff:74.125.140.109:587), connect error 10060 . Failed messages:
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host:
> smtp.gmail.com, port: 587, response: 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server
> ::ffff:74.125.140.109 (::ffff:74.125.140.109:587), connect error 10060

> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP
> host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587, response: 421 Cannot connect to SMTP
> server ::ffff:74.125.140.109 (::ffff:74.125.140.109:587), connect
> error 10060

Here is my properties file

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=*my-username*
spring.mail.password=*my-generated-password*
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

I have also added these 3 properties but still same error

```
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you be hosting that application on a remote server, or each client will have it's own server running on his local computer? If the answer is "running on a remote server" then that might not really be a problem at all, you just need to configure a firewall rules on that particular server.

If it's the latter, then you would have to either use a different protocol that is not blocked by most antiviruses, or use another remotely-hosted service that accepts the request over HTTP and handles the mailing for you.